# Can not start MongoDB community edition on Mac

Tags: mongodb, mac-os-x

Following [Install MongoDB Community Edition on macOS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/):

Started like this: `brew services start mongodb-community@6.0`

no error was raised, but when I do: `brew services list`

```
kukodajanos@Kukodas-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew services list
Name                  Status      User        File
mongodb-community     error  3584 kukodajanos ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
mongodb-community@4.2 error  3584 kukodajanos ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community@4.2.plist
```

1. I stopped and restarted.
2. Reinstalled community edition
3. Restarted my computer
4. did `sudo chmod 777 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`

What else I can do?

See this in the logs, what is wrong?

```
kukodajanos@Kukodas-MacBook-Pro ~ % tail /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log 
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-21T11:32:37.516+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-21T11:32:37.516+01:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22302,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-21T11:32:37.516+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3584M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-21T11:32:38.130+01:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":13,"message":"[1669026758:130299][4360:0x109930580], wiredtiger_open: [WT_VERB_DEFAULT][ERROR]: int __posix_open_file(WT_FILE_SYSTEM *, WT_SESSION *, const char *, WT_FS_OPEN_FILE_TYPE, uint32_t, WT_FILE_HANDLE **), 805: /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied"}}
```

Found this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60605550/239219

But databases in my case are not under `/var/lib/`

Are the files belong to `mongodb-community@6.0` these?

```
kukodajanos@Kukodas-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew list mongodb-community@6.0
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/bin/install_compass
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/bin/mongod
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/bin/mongos
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/MPL-2
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES
```

Tried this also:

```
kukodajanos@Kukodas-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb
chown: mongodb: illegal group name
```